# Java 8 Javadoc vs. XJC Warnings & Errors

Tags: linux, jaxb, java-8, javadoc, xjc

How do I use xjc to generate Java code from xsd files which have 0 Javadoc Warnings and Errors at build time when using Java 8 and not changing which Doclint being used?

I'm using an Apache-Ant build.xml file to build the codebase.

Answer (score 2):

I can't.

According to JAXB, those build problems are not blockers, ["since workaround is to pass -Xdoclint:none to javadoc executable"](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1022). =(

Yes, it is possible to hand-edit the generated Java files to get 0 Warnings and 0 Errors, but my main goal is to generate Java files that do not require hand edits (or custom plugins) under any and all circumstances.